# How to fetch images from storage folder from an add-on-domain in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I have an add-on-domain as public_html/xyz.in. I am uploading images and images are getting stored inside storage/app/public/images folder. However when I am trying to fetch images from that folder, its showing 404 not found. Please help.

```
<img src="{{ asset('storage/app/public/images/tulips.jpg') }}">
```

Answer (score 0):

The folder storage is not available to visitors. That's why you need to create a symbolic link from the public directory.

You can use artisan, to get a symbolic link

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a symbolic link of your storage folder. i.e `storage/app/public` to `public/storage`. if you have SSH access you can use `php artisan storage:link` as @wschopohl suggested. Else you can create a php script to create that symlink.

```
<?php
   $target = '/home/user/domain/storage/app/public';
   $shortcut = '/home/user/domain/storage';
   symlink($target, $shortcut);
?>
```

After running you can see storage folder in your public folder. Now you can access image with `<img src="{{ asset('storage/folder_name/image_name.jpg') }}">`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a storage link. run bellow command :

```
php artisan storage:link
```

And display:

```
<img src="{{ asset('public/storage/templates/image.png') }}" class="img img-thumbnail">
```

Read a full post: [How to display the storage folder image in Laravel](https://devnote.in/how-to-display-the-storage-folder-image-in-laravel/)